# Oauth: from mobile page access Native App, how?

Tags: php, mobile, oauth

We are setting up Oauth on our webpage. Our new webpage is set up with jquery.mobile

People are logging in by Oauth on our page.

Now for user friendly use, when visiting our webpage by mobile device, we would like to refer to the Native Mobile App like Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin or Google account instead of opening a new browser tab to log in (using credentials) with their preferred account.

Is this even possible? If so, how do we refer/redirect to their Native Mobile App on their device instead of a web url for Oauth?

Answer (score 0):

Typically there are URI's that refer to the native mobile apps with apis to use those native calls...for example , on IOS, using

```
 twitter://
```

will access the native application...if you wanted to have the native twitter app open and pull up a username you would

```
 twitter://user?screen_name=github
```

Typically if you are only using oauth and not looking for application permissions, the native apps will handle the auth automatically

One way to handle whether the native app is installed is use a redirect to the apps website if the URI returns allication not found

The APIs usually arent too hard to find for URIs

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now I would like to know the url command to ask for application permissions like: send a tweet automatically for instance. What do we use or where can we fin the uri?                 You are talking about if the uri returns if application is not found. How do we work this out? This feature would be very efficient!           Ps do you know the url for facebook application to open the 'check in places'  window or 'pages' window? Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a link to the FB diagmram and explanation of handling links whether authenticated or if native app installed http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/, related pages should describe the URI schemas you are looking for...dont forget to accept the answer her if it answered your question :)